# Integrating Mailjet API v3 wrapper as Codeigniter library

Tags: php, codeigniter, mailjet

How can I integrate the [Mailjet API PHP wrapper](https://github.com/mailjet/mailjet-apiv3-php-no-composer) into my Codeigniter installation as a library?

Is it as simple as placing the contents of [the repository](https://github.com/mailjet/mailjet-apiv3-php-no-composer) into `application/libraries/Mailjet` and then creating a `Mailjet.php` file in `application/libraries` which initializes Mailjet like shown below?

```
require 'Mailjet/vendor/autoload.php';

use \Mailjet\Resources;

$mj = new \Mailjet\Client(getenv('MJ_APIKEY_PUBLIC'), getenv('MJ_APIKEY_PRIVATE'));
```

Please let me know if I'm on the right track. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are on right track. But you don't need to create CI library. Use `Mailjet` repository library in controller as well. Just use composer as stated in CI [docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/autoloader.html).

> If you want CodeIgniter to use a Composer auto-loader, just set $config['composer_autoload'] to TRUE or a custom path in application/config/config.php.

**Step by step instruction for using github repository in CodeIgniter**

1. Set `$config['composer_autoload'] = TRUE;` in `APPPATH.'config/config.php'` [file](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/config.php#L123)
2. Put `composer.json` file with wanted repositories/projects in `APPPATH` location
3. Do the job with `composer install` command through console which will make `vendor` and other related files and folders inside
4. Use it when needed in controller or in other code as shown in example  bellow

example controller Mailman.php

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

use \Mailjet\Resources;

class Mailman extends CI_Controller
{
    private $apikey = 'apy__key__here';
    private $secretkey = 'apy__secret__here';

    protected $mj = NULL;

    public function __construct()
    {
        // $this->mj variable is becoming available to controller's methods
        $this->mj = new \Mailjet\Client($this->apikey, $this->apisecret);
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $response = $this->mj->get(Resources::$Contact);

        /*
         * Read the response
         */
        if ($response->success())
            var_dump($response->getData());
        else
            var_dump($response->getStatus());
    }
}
```

If you explicitly want to use Mailjet (or any other) repository through CI library, check in [docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/creating_libraries.html) how to create custom library and merge this code above with it. Personaly I use repositories this way to avoid unnecessarily loading and parsing sufficient libraries.