# Codeigniter 3: How to use composer packages? (Twilio SDK)

Tags: php, composer-php, twilio, codeigniter-3, traits

#### What I did so far:

I am pretty familiar with CI, but new to composer and the twilio SDK. Reading some tutorials and docs I managed to install composer and the twilio package. However the `/vendor` folder is parallel to my CI installation:

```
/var/www/html/
 - application
 - system
 - vendor
```

I have therefore edited the config.php setting the path like this:

```
$config['composer_autoload'] = '/var/www/html/vendor/autoload.php';
```

In my controller tried to use the SDK as documented in the Twilio SDK:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Test extends CI_Controller {

    use Twilio\Rest\Client;

    public function twilio()
    {
        $client = new Client($AccountSid, $AuthToken);

    }

}
```

However I get back an error:

> Fatal error: Test cannot use Twilio\Rest\Client - it is not a trait in /var/www/html/application/controllers/Test.php on line 6

#### Question: How do I correctly use Composer Packages in Codeingiter 3?

Comment: Try description I made [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38813987/integrating-mailjet-api-v3-wrapper-as-codeigniter-library/38815612#38815612).

Comment: https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `Config.php`, put these lines of code

```
$config['composer_autoload'] = TRUE;
require_once FCPATH . 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

and make changes in your controller like-

```
<?php

use Twilio\Rest\Client;

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

  class Test extends CI_Controller {

  public function twilio()
  {
    $client = new Client($AccountSid, $AuthToken);

  }
}
```

Refer:
http://theprofessionguru.com/android/how-to-load-composers-vendor-autoloadphp-in-codeigniter

Comment: Thanks - placing the `use Twilio\Rest\Client;` two lines higher did the job :)