# autoload twilio in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, twilio, codeigniter-3, twilio-php

I have just downloaded twilio-php-master.zip and extracted the file to the libraries folder in codeigniter. I would like to know what files to set on `$autoload['libraries'] = array()` to use the REST API.

Thank you.

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38813987/integrating-mailjet-api-v3-wrapper-as-codeigniter-library/38815612#38815612) and try to act accordingly (just switching libraries [mailjet->twilio]).

Comment: Please follow the following article to resolve this issue: [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41911927/class-twilio-rest-client-not-found)

Answer (score 4):

First extract the `Twilio` folder inside the twilio-php-master.zip into the same level as your applications folder in codeigniter,

Next set `$config['composer_autoload'] = 'Twilio/autoload.php';` in your `config.php`

lastly add `use Twilio\Rest\Client;` in the controller where you are going to use Twilio

Hope this helps you...

Comment: getting error on this   An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: ParseError

Message: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE)