# How to integrate razorpay payment gateway in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, payment-gateway, payment, gateway

Hi i am trying to integrate razorpay payment gateway in codeigniter. The code that I'm using is

View Code

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('user/addcredit/'); ?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <script
            src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"
            data-key="razorpay_key">
        </script>
    </div>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Controller code

```
class User extends CI_Controller
{
    public function addcredit()
    {
        require_once (APPPATH . 'base_url()/litehires/assets/razorpay-php/Razorpay.php');

        use Razorpay\Api\Api;

        $api = new Api('rzp_test_KEY_ID', ''rzp_test_KEY_ID');

        if (isset($_POST['razorpay_payment_id']) === false) {
            die("Payment id not provided");
        }

        $id = $_POST['razorpay_payment_id'];

        echo json_encode($payment->toArray());
    }
}
```

What I got to know is that I cannot use 'use' keyword inside the function. But I'm not able to find alternative way to do the integration. I haven't use composer, so would appreciate if anyone could please tell me how to integrate this payment without composer

Comment: `require_once (APPPATH . 'base_url()/litehires/assets/razorpay-php/Razorpay.php');` `base_url()` in this context shouldn't work. Maybe typo, but you also have sufficient quote character in `$api = new Api('rzp_test_KEY_ID', ''rzp_test_KEY_ID');`. [Check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38813987/integrating-mailjet-api-v3-wrapper-as-codeigniter-library/38815612#38815612) how to use integrated libraries: Put `use Some\Library` at the top of the file, above class.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily put the `use` keyword at the top of that file. If there is already an `Api` class clashing with this, you can do the following:

```
<?php

require_once (APPPATH . 'base_url()/litehires/assets/razorpay-php/Razorpay.php');

use Razorpay\Api as RazorpayApi;

class User extends CI_Controller
{
    public function addcredit()
    {
        $api = new RazorpayApi('rzp_test_KEY_ID', 'rzp_test_KEY_ID');
```

This will include the file, then `use` the class, so it is available below in the controller.

*Disclaimer*: I work for Razorpay.