# Integrating AWS PHP SDK with Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, aws-sdk, codeigniter-3, aws-php-sdk

What's the best way to integrate Amazon's [AWS SDK for PHP](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php) with Codeigniter 3.x? Installing via Composer and then creating a library? If so, what is the process for doing that?

I've found libraries on Github for [integrating just S3 with Codeigniter](https://github.com/psugand/CodeIgniter-S3), but I need to use some of AWS's other services as well (SQS, Route53, etc.), so an approach that integrates the full SDK is needed.

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38813987/integrating-mailjet-api-v3-wrapper-as-codeigniter-library/38815612#38815612) if helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using composer to install AWS SDK for PHP. It will be a lot easier for you to pick up the latest version directly without code changes since the SDK keeps on releasing new features/services/bug fixed frequently.

Also you can access new services directly when they launch by depending on latest version of SDK.