# I am trying to set up microsoft azure storage acces using code igniter. It is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am using codeigniter for a project. I need to use azure storage. So I have used composer to get the microsoft azure php libraries. I am trying to list the buckets in a model file.
I type

```
use WindowsAzure\Common\ServicesBuilder;
```

int that file. On execution, it crashes at this line.
Is it a path problem. Can someone help?
I also tried puting the require `"vendor/autoload.php"` file. It didn't help. What can I do to make it work?

Comment: Did you get any error?

Comment: You can follow [this step by step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38813987/integrating-mailjet-api-v3-wrapper-as-codeigniter-library/38815612#38815612) for installing your library of choice with composer. Check that example there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using composer, you can install CodeIgniter with one command. See [CodeIgniter Composer Installer](https://github.com/kenjis/codeigniter-composer-installer#codeigniter-composer-installer) for details.

```
composer create-project kenjis/codeigniter-composer-installer codeigniter
```

Then `cd` into your ci project path and install [Azure SDK for PHP](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php) by running the command:

```
composer require microsoft/windowsazure
```

After these done, you can use the following code to work with Azure storage in the controller.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

use WindowsAzure\Common\ServicesBuilder;

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $account = 'yourAccoutName';
        $key = 'yourAccessKey';
        $connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=$account;AccountKey=$key";
        $blobRestProxy = ServicesBuilder::getInstance()->createBlobService($connectionString);
        // ...

        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
}
```

Comment: This gave me an idea. I just created a file like the above and it worked.