# PHPOffice/Common using PHPWord in codeigniter not found

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpword, phpoffice

They have updated the plugin and replace some shared class according to this: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/releases
and upon upgrading the phpword, I encountered this error.

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Class 'PhpOffice\Common\Text' not found

Filename: Element/Text.php

Line Number: 139





<?php
include_once(APPPATH."third_party/PHPWord/Autoloader.php");
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');


use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Autoloader;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings;
Autoloader::register();
Settings::loadConfig();


class Test extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {
                $phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
                $phpWord->getCompatibility()->setOoxmlVersion(14);
                $phpWord->getCompatibility()->setOoxmlVersion(15);

                $section = $phpWord->addSection();
                $html = '<p><strong style="font-weight: 600;"This is a heading</strong></p>

                $filename = 'test.doc';

                \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Html::addHtml($section, $html);
                $objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
                $objWriter->save($filename);
                header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
                header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
                header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
                header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
                header('Expires: 0');
                header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
                header('Pragma: public');
                header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
                flush();
                readfile($filename);
                unlink($filename); // deletes the temporary file
                exit;
        }
}
```

I have use composer and I'm wondering how if to use the common shared library: https://github.com/PHPOffice/Common

Please help.

Comment: Share your controller code.

Comment: @Tpojka edited my question with the controller code

Comment: I am not sure what is `Common` for and link to docs is broken. But I understood that your main problem is `PHPWord`. Right?

Answer (score 0):

Can you ssh your server with terminal to use composer and avoid third party directory instead? I just tried to install PHPWord with composer. Successfully. Common directory is in PHPWord package by default. But I had [this issue](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/927). It can be solved [this way](https://github.com/eddturtle/PHPWord/commit/fd3cc476eb853530ae97cd16e98a0c09de69947b) or maybe even better [this way](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/1024).
I have used basic code example from [PHPWord GitHub](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord#getting-started) page.

It would be best to fork PHPWord into your own repository before fixing that line and than call your repository to avoid future breaks in case of update package.
I am not sure why they didn't fix that though.

Follow [these 4 steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38813987/integrating-mailjet-api-v3-wrapper-as-codeigniter-library/38815612#38815612) to be able to reproduce my own use of composer.

Then, your sample class should look something like:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

use PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord;

class Welcome extends CI_Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        try {
            // code example from GitHub https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord#getting-started
            // without require 'bootstrap.php' line, following 4 steps you already auto-loaded classes
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
          echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

and you should get `helloWorld.docx`, `helloWorld.odt` and `helloWorld.html` files in `FCPATH` location.